# How is the word embedding represented in the paper "Recurrent neural network based language model"?

Tags: natural-language-processing, recurrent-neural-networks, word-embedding, papers

I'm reading *"[Recurrent neural network based language model](http://www.fit.vutbr.cz/research/groups/speech/publi/2010/mikolov_interspeech2010_IS100722.pdf)"* of Mikolov et al. (2010). Although the article is straight forward, I'm not sure how word embedding $w(t)$ is obtained:

[image]

The reason I wonder is that in the classic "*[A Neural Probabilistic Language Model](http://www.jmlr.org/papers/volume3/bengio03a/bengio03a.pdf)*" Bengio et al. (2003) - they used separate embedding vector for representing each word and it was somehow "semi-layer", meaning - it haven't contains non-linearity, but they did update word embeddings during the back-propagation.

In Mikolov approach though, I assume they used simple one-hot vector, where each feature represent presence of each word. If we represent that's way single word input (like was in the Mikolov's paper) - that vector become all-zeros except single one.

Is that correct?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Input vector contains two concatenated parts. The low part represents the current word:

> word in time t encoded using 1-of-N coding [...] - size of vector x is
>   equal to size of vocabulary V (this can be in practice 30 000-200 000) plus [...]

where, as you said, 1-of-N means (see [here](https://www.quora.com/What-is-1-of-V-coding-with-relation-to-the-neural-network-language-model), 1-of-V):

> If you have a fixed-size vocabulary of symbols with V members in
>   total, each input symbol can be coded as a vector of size V with all
>   zeros except for the element corresponding to the symbol's order in
>   the vocabulary, which gets a 1.

The high part of the input vector represents the current context:

> and previous context layer [...] Size of context (hidden) layer s is
>   usually 30 - 500 hidden units.
>
> For initialization, s(0) can be set to vector of small values, like
>   0.1

the article includes this expression:

> x(t) = w(t) + s(t - 1)

that I think better to write as:

> x(t) = w(t) || s(t - 1)

to made more visible the concatenation.

Finally, paper states some improvements that breaks the 1-to-N definition of the word (low) part, in order to reduce the size of the w vector:

> we merge all words that occur less often than a threshold (in the
>   training text) into a special rare token.

Comment: so `x(t) = w(t) + s(t - 1)` is in fact concatenation of 2 vectors, rather then addition?

Comment: yes, it is. "w" and "s" have very different sizes, no addition (sum componentwise) possible.